# sshd_config: Match for requested domain?

Tags: ssh, configuration, domain-name

Like a virtual host declaration at a web server, I'd like to control sshd when a connection with a certain domain name gets established. That is, multiple domain names point to the sshd machine, which has only a single IP address.

Is it possible at all? Following doesn't seem to work:

```
Match Host some-domain.com
  ChrootDirectory /some/dir
```

If I connect from my local machine with `ssh some-domain.com` I'm not rooted to /some/dir.

Can it be done anyhow? According to this (old) [question](https://serverfault.com/q/479587/215126) and its answers it is not possible...

Comment: That hasn't changed and is unlikely to do so.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks for the link that I've already provided ;-) I'm wondering if anything might have changed. E.g. with that 'rdomain' setting, which I don't understand. And I don't know what the 'Match Host' stands for...

Comment: `Match Host` is an SSH client side directive.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Really? The [man page](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match) of sshd_config doesn't contain that information.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense in the server side, since SSH server cannot know what the domain name resolved before connecting to server's IP. The documentation could be better. `rdomain` is an OpenBSD specific construct for multiple network spaces in the kernel, and is unrelated to your queston.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen If you are sure you could create an official answer for my question.